# Gnome 3 - Unable to change date and time

Tags: linux, gnome, time

I am running Arch Linux with Gnome 3. Unfortunately, although my time and date settings in /etc/rc.conf show that HARDWARECLOCK='UTC' and TIMEZONE='America/LosAngeles'. I continue to get the timezone of Europe/London.

If I try to change the date and time via the GUI. It requires root access. After authorizing root access, the date and time may be changed; however, after closing the GUI window, it automatically reverts back to the previous incorrect timezone.

I am able to use pool.ntp.org in order to sync my time to the correct one; however, this works only for the current session and is not fixed. This solution is inconvenient since there is not always network access.

What other solutions are available for this problem?

Comment: Do you have `ntpd` or `hwclock` in *DAEMONS*? If a NTP daemon is not running, `hwclock` is necessary to store the system clock to RTC on shutdown.

Comment: hwclock is in DAEMONS. good idea though.

Comment: Seems like this is a clock skew issue. A Windows 7 partition maintains the time/date. After changing the time there, it will affect the Arch partition.